# Как собрать ios версию с ionic3?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic, ionicframework

Есть проект на ionic 3, пытаюсь собрать ios версию,
делаю следующее:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios --prod
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

открываю в Xcode, на емуляторе приложение запускает нормально но при сборе на устройство все время ошибка

> /MyPath/Debug-iphoneos/test_app.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Андроид версия собирается нормально, подскажите где может быть, ошибка буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

проблема была решена сменой ноута, все настройки оставил теже, xcode стоял последней версии.возможно проблема в самом MacBook Air

Comment: Скорее проблема с аккаунтом/сертификатами

Comment: Суть в том что аккаунт и сертификаты тежи. Читал о проблеме что компилятор не понимает моб. процессор, в основном проблема на MackBook, на Pro и  Air встречается реже. Возможно я чего то не понимаю но это единственное объяснение которое нашел.